# Mapping <Shift>-Insert to paste in gVim search field

Tags: vimrc, gvim, linux, os-clipboard

In gVim (not terminal Vim), I want to be able to paste from <Shift>-Insert (a.k.a. C-V) into the text input field of a search.  I.e. when I press "/", and go into search mode, I want to be able to paste there using <Shift>-Insert. I have these lines in my `~/.vimrc`, which does work in terminal Vim, but pasting into the search field doesn't work in gVim:

```
" map X11 cut/copy/paste to vim
imap <C-V> <C-O>:set paste<CR><C-R><C-R>+<C-O>:set nopaste<CR>
vmap <C-V> "_di<C-V><ESC>
vmap <C-C> "+ygv
vmap <C-X> "+d

if has("gui_running")
    map  <silent>  <S-Insert>  "+p
    imap <silent>  <S-Insert>  <Esc>"+pa
endif
```

Also, my gVim/Vim binary was compiled with "+clipboard".

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you are looking for `cmap`?  For example:

```
cmap <S-Insert> <C-R>+
```

Incidentally, you can use the `<C-R>+` for your `imap` as well, so you don't have to leave insert mode then enter it again:

```
imap <S-Insert> <C-R>+
```